# Loading info from a file into a list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm writing a program which will read info from a file, line by line, and then load the info into a doubly linked list. The info is loaded as a structure called tvshow:

```
typedef struct tvshow{
    char name[20];
    int epNumber;
    int year;
    float duration;
    char country[3];
    char genre[20];
}tvshow;

typedef struct node{
    tvshow inf;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}node;

void insert(node **, tvshow);
void print(node *);
FILE *safe_open(char *, char *);
void load(node **, FILE *);

int main(){
    node *head;
    head=NULL;

    FILE *in=safe_open("tvshows.txt", "r");

    load(&head, in);
    print(head);

    fclose(in);

    return 0;
    }

void insert(node **head, tvshow data){
    node *new=malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->inf=data;
    new->next=NULL;

    if (*head==NULL){
        *head=new;
        new->prev=NULL;
    }else{
        node *temp=*head;
        while (temp->next!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
     }
    temp->next=new;
    new->prev=temp;
    }
}

void print(node *head){
    while (head!=NULL){
        printf("%s %d %d %f %s %s\n", head->inf.name,head->inf.epNumber,head->inf.year, head->inf.duration,head->inf.country, head->inf.genre);
        head=head->next;
    }
}

FILE *safe_open(char *name, char *mode){
    FILE *fp=fopen(name, mode);

    if (fp==NULL){
        printf("failed to open");
        exit(1);
    }

    return fp;
}

void load(node **head, FILE *fp){
    tvshow temp;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %f %s %s", temp.name, &temp.epNumber,&temp.year, &temp.duration, temp.country, temp.genre)!=EOF){
        insert(head, temp);
    }
}
```

here is the example line from the .txt file:
        `TheSopranos 86 1999 55 USA Drama`

What is bothering me is that when I run the program, it prints the following:

```
TheSopranos 86 1999 55 USADrama Drama
```

Why USADrama? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: try changing char country[3] to char country[4] for the '\0'

Comment: @novice tried, still the same...do you have any other idea?

Comment: @novice actually it worked, my bad...thanks

Comment: cool, ill add it as an answer then

Comment: Why are you passing in pointer-to-pointers to your functions? Simple pointers are all that you really need for a linked list.

Comment: @Chimera since you first initialize the head pointer to NULL, you need to pass the head by reference in order to change its value after insertion.

Comment: @sstefan Of course. My bad. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `char country[3]` to `char country[4]` for the '\0' null character

Comment: That is true, but there are few countries that have 3-letter names. Also TV shows' `name[20]` and `genre[20]` are likely to run out of steam. Consider allocating memory for the name, and storing a pointer. Consider having a list of genres to reference, that will address any user's typo problems.

Comment: I think it's the way his files are stored. Maybe he is storing all country names as three letters

Comment: Got it. As for the countries, I forgot to add that country field refers to 3-letter abbreviation.